# graphql-django update mutation with optional fields idiom?

Tags: django, graphene-python, graphene-django

When implementing GraphQL update mutations with many (here just `a` and `b`) optional InputObjectType fields it generates a lot of boilerplate to check if the InputObjectTypes fields have been passed. Is there some idiom which is considered best practice w.r.t. this topic?

```py
# <app>/models.py

from django.db import models

class Something(models.Model):
    a = models.CharField(default='')
    b = models.CharField(default='')


# <app>/schema.py

import graphene
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType
from .models import Something


class SomethingType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Something


class SomethingInput(graphene.InputObjectType):
    # all fields are optional
    a = graphene.String()
    b = graphene.String()


class SomethingUpdateMutation(graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        id = graphene.ID(required=True)
        something_data = SomethingInput(required=True)

    something = graphene.Field(SomethingType)

    def mutate(self, info, id, something_data):
        something_db = Something.objects.get(pk=id)
        # checking if fields have been passed or not and
        # only change corresponding db value if value has been passed
        if something_data.a is not None:
            something_db.a = something_data.a
        if something_data.b is not None:
            something_db.b = something_data.b
        something_db.save()
        return SomethingUpdateMutation(something=something)


class Mutation(object):
    # project schema inherits from this class
    something_update_mutation = SomethingUpdateMutation.Field()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
def mutate(self, info, **kwargs):
    user = info.context.user
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        user.k = v
    user.save()
    return UpdateUser(user=user)
```

But still, I'm also finding some elegant way to do it.

But, if user wanna remove the content from the field, then what will you do since you are checking `!None`. IMO, the best practice, when we update a data we send all the data with the updated fields. So we don't need to check, is something empty or not.

Comment: I don't think it's the best practice to send all data when updating a model. The reason is that you'd have to store all the model's data in the system which interacts with your GraphQL API e.g. a client in the frontend code. This means you'd have to either query all model data before someone changes data in a form OR you'd have to store the model data in the frontend. The later is even worse. Having to store state in another place than the backend is bad.

Comment: You need to use `setattr(user, k, v)` here, `user.k = v` creates a new attribute `k` on the `user` object (`django.db.models.Model` instances are mutable)